# Ok, Where is mongoose API about document.save() callback argument?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, doc

English is not my first language, but I'm trying hard.

The problem is that I'm using a project using Mongoose, but I can't find a description of **the parameter of the callback function** in document.save().

1. [genious answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33019804/how-does-mongooses-save-callback-work)
2. [Official Doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-save)

The link gives me an accurate answer to my question, and the link's the genious who answered  explains that there are three things in the callback parameter, but I can't find such an explanation anywhere in the official document, not just an option parameter, **Callback parameter**

But it's explained as if it's in the official document.

Am I a fool? I want to erase this pathetic question quickly. Help me, Bill Gates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guide on how to execute queries [mentions the following](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#executing):

> All callbacks in Mongoose use the pattern: `callback(error, result)`. If an error occurs executing the query, the `error` parameter will contain an error document, and `result` will be null. If the query is successful, the `error` parameter will be null, and the result will be populated with the `results` of the query.

Since the documentation for `Document.prototype.save()` says nothing but:

> `[fn] «Function»` optional callback

So you know this function is no exception to the rule. As such, `doc.save((err, doc) => {  })` is the signature of the callback.

Comment: Thank you so much. That's the answer I wanted. As a junior, I'd like to ask you one question. Do you read all the official documents from the beginning? Am I supposed to study like that? I never thought this would be included in the query category.

Comment: Mongoose's documentation isn't that long, so reading the guides from "Schemas" through "Populate" is very do-able and informative. Some subjects, such as Discriminators are a bit advanced, you could peek at it, but there's no need to know all documentation by heart—if you give it a quick glance, you'll know _what exists and what's possible_ so you can later look it up when you actually need it.